# IIS - Share pages among sites

Tags: iis, iis-7, web

I have a couple of applications/sites running on different ports on my IIS server. I need to publish pages that are common between these sites. What is the easiest way to do this?
I can't redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a virtual directory in all your sites that share the same folder.
when you change the page on the "base" folder, it will reflect on all the sites.